# Is there an equivalent of c++ shared_ptr in swift 3?

Tags: c++, swift

I know strong (default) and weak (with the weak keyword) references in swift 3, but is there an equivalent of shared references?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really know C++, so can you explain the behaviour or shared references so that more people can answer the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory management paradigm in Swift is different from C++ since it inherits the retain-release mechanism (through ARC) from Objective-C. As you might expect, C++'s solution puts less responsibility on the compiler, is more expressive and optimised but also more complex to work with.

So, to answer your question: `strong` (which is default) works basically like `shared_ptr`, `weak` is like `weak_ptr` and `unique_ptr` doesn't have a direct equivalent. However, some strong vars might act like `unique_ptr` if the compiler is able to guarantee the uniqueness of the pointer (e.g. you create and destroy an object in the same scope - like a function's body - without assigning it to any var)

Of course, this only applies to reference types. Value types are just copied.

Comment: Is there a directive or function in swift that can tell if a variable is reference or value type ?

Comment: If the value is castable to AnyObject, then it's a reference type. Otherwise, it's a value type. ('value is AnyObject' in swift).

Answer (score 4):

Swift applies [ARC (automatic reference counting)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) of *strong* references to decide when to free up memory used by a *reference type* instance (namely, when the number of strong references to that object is zero). ARC and its reference counting runs automatically, but holds similiarities to the explicit use of C++'s `std::shared_ptr`; the latter will allow an object pointed to (by shared ptrs) to be destroyed (e.g. by a supplied deletor) only when all smart pointers pointing to the object has gone out of scope or been explicitly reset (/nulled).

In the example above, you can consider the strong immutables (references) `foo` and `bar` (the latter return from `foobar()`) as the `std::smart_ptr`'s equivalents of C++: they both point to the same `Foo` object, and only when both are out of scope will the object be deinitialized.

```
class Foo {
    init() { print("initializing") }
    deinit { print("deinitialized") }
}

func foobar() -> Foo {
    let foo = Foo() // strong reference
    let bar = foo   // another strong reference 
    // total "shared" count is now 2
    return bar
    // reference associateced with 'foo' goes 
    // out of scope, but the reference associateced
    // with 'bar' is returned from the function, and
    // thus, ARC still keeps the Foo instance alive.
}

func bar() {
    print("calling foobar ...")
    let bar = foobar() // retains the reference from 'bar' in foobar()
    print("foo() is now out of scope")
    print("leaving bar() scope ...")
} // 'bar' of bar() goes out of scope: Foo object should be deinitialized

bar()
/* calling foobar ...
   initializing
   foo() is now out of scope
   leaving bar() scope ...
   deinitialized             */
/* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^- ok */
```

Answer (score 2):

Normal *vars* (Without weak or unowned modifiers) have similar semantics as the shared_ptr.

Comment: I think  that normal vars are strong reference

Comment: @Bob5421 Yes, but the pointer holds a reference counter of who holds the reference, and it's deleted when the counter reaches zero, same as the shared_ptr.